# Specflow test project fails build .NET 5 windows7

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5, specflow

I get this error building my specflow test project

[image]

I cannot figure out why I get these compile bugs..
I am quite sure it has to do with use .NET 5,
don't have a lib folder, where the libraries/nugets are stored...

my project looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.57" />
  <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.MsTest" Version="3.9.74" />
  <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.10" />
  <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.10" />
  <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.7.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <OutputPath>..\Bin\Debug</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
      <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <OutputPath>..\Bin\Release</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="Drivers\" />
  <Folder Include="Hooks\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
 <ProjectReference Include="..\MagVenture.Utilities.UI\MagVenture.Utilities.UI.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I cannot figure it out... - there is a twirl somewhere that I didn't see..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the compiler error message. It can be difficult to read in an image. Plus, you cannot copy and paste the error message to search.

Comment: Can you include more of the .csproj file too?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Just added the rest of the csproj file.. - not that interesting, I think, but a good place 2 look. (and I migth be wrong)

Comment: one step further.... I just added NU5100 to the list of ignored warnings... 
(and it builds nicely, but the specflow generated unit test fails...
- and now it it succeedes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the NU5100 warning, when treating warnings as errors.

it is due to the .NET framework versions policies about location in lib folder.